# Limit of function $f(x) = 1 (x \in \mathbb{Z})$ as $x$ approaches $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Function $f$ is only defined for integers $x$ and $f(x) = 1$ for all integers $x$.

Would the limit exist as $x$ approaches $0$? Using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, we can find $\delta$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ since the value $|f(x) - 1|$ is just $0$ for all $x$ in $domf$. It seems right with the definition but it is very counterintuitive. Would the limit not exist since there is no accumulation point in $f$'s domain?

Comment: On the one hand, the specification of $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ is normally restricted to those values of $x$ that happen to be in the domain of the function.  On the other hand, my understanding, which could be mistaken, is that the issue of whether the limit of a function exists, as $x$ approaches $a$ is normally restricted to those situations where there exists an infinite subsequence of the Domain whose limit is $a$.  That is not the case here.  Therefore, unless I am mistaken, the question of whether the limit exists as $x$ approaches $a$ is not appropriate for this function.

Comment: In book Rudin W. - Principles of mathematical analysis-McGraw Hill (1976) - on page 83 you can find general definition of limit, where limit definition is taken with respect to domain of function. This means restrict inequality in limit definition only to points from domain. By this generalization limit exists in your case.

Comment: @zkutch Interesting, but I guess its the 'expanded version' or like different point of view stuff, right?

Comment: I'll write, let me little time, pls.

Comment: The fact that the answers are quite contradictory comes from the fact that the question is, in fact, unprecise : to be perfectly clear, one should add which topology you consider.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe What would one call the topologies in each case?

Comment: @Vue  A constant function between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, $f:X\to Y$, is always continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Since the answers provided are a bit contradictory, let me try to give one that's more nuanced:

In my real analysis class we handled the definition of a limit as such that the limit exists and equals what you would think it should equal: $\lim_0 f = 1$. We're allowing all points in the domain to be points in which we can take a limit (whether the limit exists or not is a different question).

However, in some (calculus or real analysis) textbooks we'd like the point $a$ (here $0$) where we'd like to know the limit of $f$ of to be a limit point (or accumulation point), meaning, every neighbourhood of $a$ (here $0$) needs to have at least one other point in it other than $a$ that is also in the domain of $f$. Here that's not the case, since $(0.5, 0.5)$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ but contains no other elements that $0$ from $Z$. (Note that this is different from what you suggested, it only matters if $0$ is a limit point or not, not that there are no other limit points.)

In conclusion: *it depends*.

Comment: Thanks for the conclusion. Quite surprising that it depends, especially in math where everything needs to be perfect as possible.

Comment: @Vue I'm not specifically into analysis, but in general it happens quite a lot that there are many different variations of definitions that authors decide to use.

Comment: For example, there is some disagreement if the natural numbers should be defined as $N = \{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$ or as $N = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$, and it usually depends on the author's taste, but it could also depend on convenience. That doesn't mean one is more perfect than the other, or their math is of a lesser sort, or whatever; it doesn't change the truth of the theorems and it's easy to translate the stuff into what your own convention.

Comment: Your claim about Rudin is incorrect (he also requires $a$ to be a limit point).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @HansLundmark, I just stole the example from a different answerer! (But I think my answer still stands.)

Answer (score 0):

The limit does not exist since the function is only defined for integers. Notice that the function is undefined for the "neighbourhood" of $x=0$.

The epsilon-delta definition basically says, I encourage you to draw a graph and see it graphically, that for every neighbourhood of a value there must be an ever smaller neighbourhood. This recursively means you get an infinitesimal neighbourhood. It does not happen with your function.

Answer (score 0):

In book Rudin W. - Principles of mathematical analysis-McGraw Hill (1976) - on page 83 you can find general definition of limit:

Let $X,Y$ are metric spaces and $f$ maps $E \subset X$ into $Y$ and $p$ is limit point of $E$. We write
$$\lim\limits_{x\to p}f(x)=q$$
if there is $q \in Y$ with following property: $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \delta >0$ such that for all points $x \in E$ we have
$$0<d_X(x,p)<\delta \Rightarrow d_Y(f(x), q)<\varepsilon $$
where symbols $d_X, d_Y$ refers to distances in $X,Y$ respectively.

This definition you can directly apply to your case with $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $E=\mathbb{Z}$.

**Addition.**

Accordingly to written in comment below, this definition can be extended for any $p\in E$, even in isolated point case.

Comment: $E$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ in my case, right?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: This definition seems like an expanded form of the definition we learn in Calculus. Is it something like "we can say that ~"? I'm confused.. Since there are no accumulation points in $\mathbb{Z}$ but the epsilon delta definition requires $a$ to be the accumulation point.

Comment: This argument should work for an isolated point, right? Because if by limit point you mean point which every neighbourhood contains an element other than the point, this doesn't look like it applies here.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur you are right in that on page $83$ (and same above) is used $p$ as limit point, but, farther, on page $84$ and page $86$ is considered case with $p$ isolated and we can use same definition. For example, this gives, that in every isolated point any function is continuous (p.$86$). Let me say, that, imho, it's correct to wait my answer on your remark and after it down vote, not before.

Comment: I'm not sure  what you mean by the down-vote comment, since I didn't vote on your answer. I just think that is best to clarify what you mean by limit point, since alot of times the definition usually execludes this setting.

Comment: @zkutch: You're misquoting Ruding in your comment. On page 84 he says that things are assumed to be as in Def. 4.1, including the fact that $p$ should still be a limit point of $E$. At the top of page 86, he's talking only about *continuity* at an isolated point, not about limits. In order to reconnect to what he has said about limits, he again (in Theorem 4.6) assumes that that $p$ is a limit point of $E$. Rudin's definition of limit does **not** give the answer $1$ to the question asked here, since $0$ is not a limit point of $\mathbb{Z}$ (in the topology induced from $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @Hans Lundmark. In my previous comment, I already wrote  that there is a limit point property in the definition of the limit. I also already wrote in the same comment that on page 86 speech is about continuity. Where is the "misquoting" one you mentioned? You repeated what I already wrote. (continued)

Comment: (cont.)The idea that I am trying to convey is the **following**: since the continuity of a function at an isolated point is a degenerate concept of continuity, one can also consider in same way the concept of a limit at an isolated point. If, in the case of continuity, we have the only point in a sufficiently small neighborhood, then in the case when this is just a limit, we have empty set; therefore, the fulfillment of any condition in the second part of the implication occurs automatically, i.e. the same degenerate understanding of the limit is obtained, which is discussed in the question.

Comment: You *could* do that, but Rudin doesn't, and if you do it, then you lose uniqueness of limits. In this case, you could say that $f(x) \to 1$ as $x \to 0$, but it would be equally true that $f(x) \to 43$ as $x \to 0$. And then using the notation $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ wouldn't be correct, since it would imply that $1=43$. You could avoid that problem by changing $0 < d_X(x,p) < \epsilon$ to $0 \le d_X(x,p) < \epsilon$, which actually some sources do (but not Rudin), but that brings with it other consequences that may (or may not, depending on taste) be considered undesirable.

Comment: Anyway, by Rudin's definitions, the function $f$ in question is continuous at $0$ (since $0$ is an isolated point in the domain $D_f = \mathbb{Z}$), but it does not have a limit at $0$ (for precisely the same reason).

Comment: Conclusion with $1=43$, of course, is incorrect. Without limit point we have definition with  notations with ambiguously defined meanings, such as, for example, in asymptotic. Simply understand it as set. Generally we are speaking about proper and not proper filters and which one is considered desirable depend on contemplating context. And last remark is correct without last part.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, we'd want to write $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \alpha$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta = \delta(\epsilon) > 0$ such that $|f(x) - \alpha| < \epsilon$ for any $x\not= 0$ in the domain of $f$ with $|x| < \delta$. The problem here is that for $0 < \delta < 1$, there is no such $x$. The implication above therefore vacuously holds for any $\alpha$ at all; just take $\delta = \frac{1}{2}$ for any $\epsilon$. Having limits not be uniquely defined is certainly a problem, so it's customary to require that there has to exist at least one $x$ above. More specifically, we require for a limit $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ that $a$ be a *limit point* of the domain $X$ of $f$; that is, there exists for any $\epsilon > 0$ some $x\not = a$ in $X$ with $|x - a| < \epsilon$. It's not hard to show that with that extra caveat, limits are unique if they exist. The same definition and limit construction can be extended to more general metric spaces, topological spaces, etc., but that's the basic idea.